# Is `std::shared_mutex` virtually a superset of `std::mutex`?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, stdmutex, shared-lock

`std::shared_mutex` can provide an exclusive lock like `std::mutex`. Plus it extends the synchronization capabilities by allowing the parallel read-only accesses to the multiple threads.

Under the hood the number of machine instructions *might* be lesser for `std::mutex`. But at a practical level, while reading about their usage I feel that `std::shared_mutex` can potentially supersede or even deprecate `std::mutex`.

In other words, is there any place where `std::mutex` has to be used over `std::shared_mutex`?

Comment: idk. Lets imagine you have an object with a (toy example) `mutable size_t counter;` which is incremented each time a `const` qualified method is called. With `std::shared_mutex` invoking such a method would yield UB (data race).  But exclusive ownership prevents it

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: That represents an API that's actively lying to you. If a function has `const` access to some object, it *ought* to ensure that there are no data races. If that object stores some `mutable` member that gets modified in `const` functions, the onus is on *those functions* to synchronize access to the `mutable` member.

Comment: @NicolBolas not necessarily. One can design a class with no concurrent access in mind. I don't advocate for thoughless usage of `mutable`, but this situation is not very far from "probalbe". And with a tendency for some (even famous) libraries to overuse `pImpl` idion, you never can tell for yourself. Hence, in production code beter to use `std::mutex` if you are not entirely sure about thread safety

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: "*One can design a class with no concurrent access in mind.*" Then it should be part of that class's documentation that it should not be concurrently accessed *at all*. "*if you are not entirely sure about thread safety*" If you're not "entirely sure about thread safety" then you *don't have thread safety*.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39496504

Comment: Also, the [*SharedMutex*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SharedMutex) requirement is a strict superset of [*Mutex*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Mutex). You could even have a `std::shared_timed_mutex`, but as long as you only used it as a *Mutex*, it would have the desired semantics (if only less efficiently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes`std::shared_mutex` is a powerful synchronization primitive that can be used to implement both read/write locks and exclusive locks which makes it more flexible than `std::mutex` in many ways.there are still several scenarios where `std::mutex` would be preferable over `std::shared_mutex`.

- **Performance:** `std::mutex` is often simpler and thus faster than
  `std::shared_mutex`. A `std::shared_mutex` typically requires more
  overhead to manage shared access rights. If you don't need the
  ability to allow multiple simultaneous readers, the simpler
  `std::mutex` will often be faster.
- **Memory:** `std::shared_mutex` can consume more memory than `std::mutex`
  due to the extra data needed to manage multiple reader threads.
- **Concurrency Scenario:** If the lock is mostly used for writing rather
  than reading, a simple std::mutex could be preferable since the use
  case does not really benefit from the `std::shared_mutex`
  functionality.
- **Complexity:**  `std::shared_mutex` comes with more operations (lock,
  try_lock, unlock, lock_shared, try_lock_shared, unlock_shared) which
  could add unnecessary complexity to the code if only mutual exclusion
  is required.

So, `std::shared_mutex` can offer benefits in terms of allowing multiple readers, if your primary use case is simply to provide exclusive access to a resource `std::mutex` could still be a simpler and more efficient choice.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` is a functional superset of `std::array`. Anything an `array` can do, a `vector` can do as well.

But that's not a good excuse to avoid using `array` when it is obviously appropriate (ie: statically sized, no need for heap allocation, etc).

Likewise, `shared_mutex` *could* be used in any place that `mutex` could. But that doesn't mean you *should*.

The types you use communicates something to the people who read your code. If you use `shared_ptr`, you are communicating to users that ownership of this object is being *shared*. That's what the name means. Using `shared_ptr` when you only use it for unique ownership of a resource says either that you expect to share it in the future or you don't know what you're doing.

Using `shared_mutex` communicates that users are expected to acquire shared locks to this mutex. This says something about the access patterns of code trying to access the guarded data. It means that the data will be read concurrently by a lot of code, but will only occasionally need exclusive access by some restricted subset of code.

And as with `shared_ptr`, using it in cases where this does not happen is a miscommunication of what is going on in your code.

And that ignores the performance implications. `shared_mutex` and its locks aren't free, after all. Any "practical level" should not throw performance away.

Comment: Though I get what you want to say, the equating between `std::array` and `std::vector` is a wrong example, at least for the future visitors. They are quite different (static vs dynamic). It cannot be treated like `std::mutex` and `std::shared_mutex`. I am comparing "red apple" and "green apple", where you are comparing "apple" and "pine-apple".

Comment: @iammilind: "*They are quite different (static vs dynamic).*" Anyplace you could use a static array is a place you could use a *dynamic* one. Being static is just a special case of dynamic. Just like being not shared is a special case of being shared.